# gdb: set a breakpoint on a function that's not yet defined

Tags: gdb

It used to be the case that, if you tried to set a breakpoint on a symbol that's not defined, gdb would offer to set it anyway, in case it will be loaded dynamically later.

However, with gdb 8.3-6 that doesn't happen.

```
(gdb) break foo
Function "foo" not defined.
```

My use case is that I need to debug a JIT-compiled function, which will be dynamically loaded after it's compiled by the program itself. How can I set a breakpoint on such a function?

This is on Fedora GNU/Linux 30.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

By default, when GDB cannot find the breakpoint location, it queries you whether a pending breakpoint should be created, see [documentation](https://sourceware.org/gdb/onlinedocs/gdb/Set-Breaks.html):

```
set breakpoint pending auto

    This is the default behavior. When GDB cannot find the breakpoint location, it queries you whether a pending breakpoint should be created.
```

The query looks like this:

```
Make breakpoint pending on future shared library load? (y or [n])
```

But this may not happen if you have disabled confirmations with `set confirm off`.

So you can either enable confirmations with `set confirm on` (if you have disabled them previously), or you can always set pending breakpoints on unrecognized breakpoint locations with `set breakpoint pending on`.